# Using Breakpoint to log Value Of Particular Key In Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, dictionary, breakpoints

How to log the value of a particular key of dictionary **using break points**,

What i know is,

We can use `NSLog` and
We can also log a message using `@exp@` format (see attached image),

In my case, this (`Value Of Title Key Is : @someRandomDictionary@`, the command in popup) logs all the keys of dictionary, but i want to see only the value of particular key.

[image]

Is there any possibility to do so !

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `po` (print object command) like so:

[image]

The `po` command takes an arbitrary expression, that returns an object and prints it’s description in the console. In this case, it will print the value for the specified key, or `nil` in case it does not exist.

Comment: To the OP, note that Teo is using the "Debugger command" action, not the log message command. It offers more options. There's "po", which is for backwards-compatibility with the GCD debugger, and then there's "expression" ("e" for short") which can be used for a wider range of expressions.

Comment: thanks for your answer but with `Debugger Command` (po), we cannot add static strings(`Value Of Title Key Is :` in my case), which helps us in identifying the log easily.

Comment: Why not? try: ``po [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Title key is: %@", dict[@"key"]]``. The ``po`` command can be called on any object or expression.

Comment: I tried this and (in Xcode 7.2.1) it doesn't work: the Objective-C parser in lldb is apparently not clever enough to recognize that `-stringWithFormat:` takes a list of arguments, and I get the error message `error: too many arguments to method call, expected 1, have 2`.  The apparent workaround is to have multiple actions in the breakpoint window: one Log Message and one Debugger Command.  Awkward, but it gets the info into the console.